# Reading tsv column and store in a dictionary resulting in None values

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, text

I have a tsv file with the following format:

```
first   44  90  org
second  80  49  sport
third   50  52  NIL
```

The file was written by the following code:

```
id = first
before = 44
after = 90
taregt = org
with open('/path/to/file.tsv', 'w') as f:
    result = u'\t'.join([
        id,
        Before,  
        After,
         target])
    f.write(result+'\n')
```

And i would like to read the two middle columns into two dictionaries as `value` and the first column as a `key`. I have the following sample compilable code however it stores the values as `None`.

```
start = {}
end = {}
with open('/path/to/file.tsv', 'rd') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.decode('utf-8').split('\t')

        key = parts[0]
        print(key)

        start[key] = parts[1]
        end[key] = parts[2]

        print(key , start.get(key), end.get(key))
```

the printed output is:

> (u'(first)', None, None)

I'm using python 2.7. Thank you in advance.

Comment: beware of `start[y]` and with `end[y]`, instead of `y` it goes `key`

Comment: it works perfect for me (ensuring that file.tsv is separated by tabs). Can you corroborate that the file has tabs and not spaces?

Comment: @lucas thank you just edited the question will add to the question how the file was written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mode as `rd` in python. Use either `rb` or `rU`. your code will work fine.

```
start = {}
end = {}
with open('path to file', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split('\t')
        key = parts[0]
        # print(key)
        # print parts
        start[key] = parts[1]
        end[key] = parts[2]

        print(key , start.get(key), end.get(key))
```

Comment: surprisingly it's no the cause of the incorrect output but it's indeed a wrong file reading method which the interpreter decided to ignore. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm for me.

Check if you using correct mode to read the file.

Comment: hi, what do you mean by mode? as declared I used 'rd'.

Comment: I suppose there is no mode like 'rd'. Are you referring to 'rb' ? or else it could be 'rD'